aws s3 PreSignedUrl used once and expired
Is there a way to use aws s3 PreSignedUrl only once and then expire PreSignedUrl? You can shorten the PreSignedUrl expiration time, but I think that is wrong.

No. It is not possible to create a pre-signed URL that can only be "used once".
It is not possible to 'disable' a pre-signed URL or force the expiry to any time sooner.
(Well, the reality is that the pre-signed URL uses the permissions of the IAM entity that signed the URL, so you could remove permissions from that entity and then the pre-signed URL will also lose the permissions, but this is not a suitable approach to meet your requirements.)
If you want a "one-off URL", then you would need to code an app that enforces this behaviour without using a pre-signed URL.
